# Strange behavior of type casting

Tags: c#, interface, casting, activator

I'm trying create some type from assembly. That type implements interface `IDerrivedInterface`, which inherits from interface `IBaseInterface`. So, I'm going to create instance of type, that implements `IBaseInterface`:

```
if (assembly != null)
{
     ObjTypes = assembly.GetTypes(); 
     foreach (var objType in ObjTypes)
     {
         try
         {
             var type = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
             if (type is IBaseInterface)
             {
                  list.Add((IBaseInterface) type);                
             }
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             int a = 0;
         }
     }
}
```

There is type, which implements `IDerrivedInterface` in `assembly`. But the line of code `list.Add((IBaseInterface) type)`  is not executed. I was trying to debug this: I added `type is IBaseInterface` to "Watches" and that value was `True`. What is the reason of that behavior?

**UPD:**
list - is simple List<>. I think it does not matter. No exception is thrown.
`IDerrived` interface inherits from `IBaseInterface`:

```
interface IBaseInterface
{
//
}
interface IDerrivedInterface : IBaseInterface
{
}
//and a class in assembly:
class SomeType : IDerrivedInterface
{
}
```

**UPD2:**
The assembly is loaded from some folder. There are several assemblies and several other files in that folder. I am iterating through all files with a ".dll" extension. Then I collect all the objects whose type implements `IBaseInterface` to the list. My type (which implements `IBaseInterface`) and the declaration of `IBaseInterface` are placed in different assemblies.
 So, if there is no assembly (which contains the declaration of `IBaseInterface`), it works. But if there is that assembly (and it processed before assembly with Type) it does not work.

**UPD3:**
There are several different interfaces, which implement that type. Moreover, that type is derivied from some `BaseClass`. It should work, but it doesn't..

Here is [some question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596796/net-unable-to-cast-object-to-interface-it-implements?rq=1) about another error, but there is one aswer about accesing two assemblies in different contexts. Maybe it is my case. Because the Library (let it be "L1") has reference to the Library (L2), where the declaration of the interfaces is placed. And there is one more library (L3), which contains the declaration of class, that implements interfaces from L2 (thats why L3 has reference to L2 too). So I am debugging in L1 (which has a reference to L2) and it loads the assemblies L2 and L3). Maybe that is why I have this problem..

Comment: Are you saying it stepped into the `if` block and threw no exception but the `list` did not contain the type?

Comment: Only create instances of type which you **need**, don't create instances of all types and pick your need. Also post some code which reproduces the problem. At this moment we can't tell what's wrong.

Comment: What kind of object is your `list` ?

Comment: Why don't you check whether the type implements the interface you want *before* attempting to create an instance of it?

Comment: I think the op means that `IDerivedInterfaces` inherits from `IBaseInterface` and because of this, the `is` doesn't recognise objects from inherited interfaces?

Comment: @Sayse that sounds remarkably unlikely

Comment: @Sayse Though he did mention that `type is IBaseInterface` values to `true`

Comment: IMO, the important thing to look at here is: what exception was thrown? Perhaps log `ex.Message` in the `catch` block. Also: what is `list`? is it a simple list of some kind? or is it something custom that could do things like: not add items when requested if it is a Friday and the moon is in venus.

Comment: @Both - Just a guess at the op's problem since the only way I can see that the line isn't executed is either that `is` condition doesn't get satisfied or the line hasn't been stepped over yet, I am also skeptical

Comment: I think it might be a debugging error that he does not see the pointer going in. Are you sure you are in DEBUG mode and not RELEASE?

Comment: Can you try IsAssignableFrom() before actually creating the objects. Just a suggestion

Comment: Yes, I`m in DEBUG mode. I place breakpoint on line with `if (type is IBaseInterface)`. And when it should go in (in "Watches" is True), it doesn`t go in, it skips this line, like that is False. I have updated question.

Comment: What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: @Marwie. There is no exception. :(

Comment: if you debug what kind of object will you find when looking at `type` just after it has been created?

Comment: @Marwie, it is right type. And everything is fine and the condition should be true and type should be added to the list. But no,list is empty. I'm going to add some description,when it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolve it using post-build event and copying only 1 dll to subfolder(where program search DLL with types). Before that, there were several dependent DLLs, that as I understand give me wrong behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The assembly would contain the three types IBaseInterface,IDerrivedInterface and a class implementing the IDerrivedInterface. The line

```
          var type = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
```

will throw exception as you can not create an object of type interface.Since a variable of interface type can hold the reference of the object of the class implementing the interface but can not be an object it self. For the class the code

```
        if (type is IBaseInterface)
         {
              list.Add((IBaseInterface) type);                
         }
```

will be executed successfully provided that the list is of IBaseInterface.

Edited: Adding the code.

I made a ClassLibrary as below.

```
namespace ClassLibrary
{
    public interface IBaseInterface
    {
    }
    public interface IDerivedInterface : IBaseInterface
    {
    }

    public class Class1:IDerivedInterface
    {

    }
}
```

And in Another project i executed following code.

```
        List<IBaseInterface> list = new List<IBaseInterface>();
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("ClassLibrary.dll");
        if (assembly != null)
        {
            var ObjTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
            foreach (var objType in ObjTypes)
            {
                try
                {
                    var type = Activator.CreateInstance(objType);
                    if (type is IBaseInterface)
                    {
                        list.Add((IBaseInterface)type);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    int a = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

It throws exception for the first two interfaces and added an item for the class type.

Comment: yes, I understand it. But there is no items in list, although there is   type in that assembly, which implements that interface.

Comment: @Alexey I have edited my solution and written the code that I am able to execute successfully as per per my explanation.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it. And place declaration of interfaces and class to different libraries. And it works fine. But in real project it still doesn`t works. It means there is something more..that  I  ignored. For example, this type is not simple implements that interface, it is derivied from another class and implements several interfaces more.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the problem is that the line `list.Add((IBaseInterface) type);` does not get executed.

Are you sure that your IDE (I guess Visual Studio) is set on DEBUG and not RELEASE? Maybe you just don't see it gets executed.

Also maybe you have an exception there and you catch it somewhere else. If that `if` contains a TRUE, then it must go inside the `if` statement.

Comment: It is DEBUG mode. There is no exception, when it process my type which implements that interface. But it not added to the list. Although, the condition is true in "Watches" window.