# Immediate window evaluates to true while debugging evaluates to false?

Tags: c#, debugging, types, reflection, comparison

### TL;DR

*I had two separate copies of my interface. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532053/9893154) on the duplicate, or my update at the bottom of this question for a breakdown of the cause.*

---

### Summary

I'm loading types from assemblies using reflection:

```
foreach (string assemblyPath in assemblyPaths) {
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
    if (assembly.GetTypes().Any(a => typeof(IChannel).IsAssignableFrom(a))) {
        DoSomethingCool();
    }
}
```

When I debug this code, I stop at the logical evaluation with a breakpoint, and check the answer in the immediate window, which evaluates to `true`:

[image: screenshot of immediate window]

When I continue execution of my code, the block for the `if` statement never executes, which leads me to assume that it evaluates to `false` when that line executes. However, I think something wonky is going on that I'm just not seeing.

- I've tried restarting Visual Studio and my computer, just-in-case it was a software issue.
- I've tried reversing the logic to `a.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IChannel))`<sub>1</sub>.
- I've also reviewed the results of `.GetTypes()` and the type I'm looking for is there.
- I performed the same check, on the type I'm looking for (`.GetTypes()[0]`), and it evaluated to `true` as expected.

<sub>1: This evaluates to `false` in the immediate window and doesn't enter the block, as I'd expect.</sub>

---

### Question

What are other reasons that could cause this inconsistency while debugging?

---

### **Answer**

The cause of my issue was the fact that `IChannel` was declared in a library that the executing assembly contained a reference to, but the loaded assembly also contained a reference to that assembly. However, the loaded assembly had it's own local copy of the library containing the definition for `IChannel`.

I eventually found the answer, through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596796/net-unable-to-cast-object-to-interface-it-implements), to which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6532053/9893154), was the most helpful (in my case), particularly this excerpt:

> I nearly got mad - but then I found out the whole problem. By compiling the plugin there was not only the "Plugin.dll" but the "Library.dll" written to the "./Plugins" directory. By accidentally loading the "Library.dll" every time with my PluginManager I now had two types of "IPlugin" - one in the actual "Library.dll" that is used from the main assembly and one that was loaded through my PluginManager - and those were incompatible!

I'm leaving this question up because finding this answer would've been a much faster process if there was a result on the web for my question title. I was actually grasping at straws and found the question that answered mine through some additional steps:

- I changed my `.Any` predicate to check for `.GetInterface("IChannel") != null`.
- I created an instance of the desired type using `Activator`.
- I tried to cast the instance back to `IChannel`.

To demonstrate the above:

```
var type = assembly.GetTypes().First(f => f.GetInterface("IChannel") != null);
var instance = (IChannel)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

<sub>There may be syntax issues with the snippet above, please do your due diligence before performing a copypasta. I've long since removed this snippet from my code as it was just for testing purposes.</sub>

Comment: Do you have more than one `IChannel`?

Comment: Rather than `if` directly on the condition, can you assign the condition to a boolean variable, then `if` on the boolean? If so, what is the value of the boolean?

Comment: @mjwills this was the problem, and I literally just solved it. Adding a link to the answer I finally found that helped.

Comment: this question is being indicated as a duplicate to a question that doesn't have an accepted answer and didn't provide any indication to their issue being related to duplicate interfaces - can you add a permalink in this comment section on which answer addresses this question?  ...to that end, what was the actual issue with this question? you defined `IChannel` in two different assemblies? and `assemblyPaths` didn't include the corresponding interface being `IsAssignableFrom` from/by `a`?

Comment: @BrettCaswell that is correct. I marked it as a duplicate last night before calling it a day (I had been fighting with it for a few hours). I updated my post this morning to reflect which answer fixed my issue, and what the issue ended up being. My apologies for the delay in that.