# Getting InvalidCastException with a Plugin architecture

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a plugin architecutre which is using a Shared DLL to implement a plugin interface and a base plugin class (eg. IPlugin & BasePlugin). The shared DLL is used by both the Plugin and the main application.

For some reason, when I try to cast an object that was instantiated by the main application to the shared plugin interface (IPlugin), I get an `InvalidCastException` saying I cannot cast this interface.

This is despite:

- The class definitely implementing the plugin interface.
- The Visual Studio debugger saying that "(`objInstance is IPlugin`)" is true when I mouse-over the statement, despite the same 'if' condition evaluating as false when I step-through the code or run the .exe.
- The Visual Studio *Immediate Window* also confirms that the above condition is true **and** that is it possible to cast the object successfully.
- I have cleaned/deleted all bin folders and also tried both VS2019 and VS2022 with exactly the same outcome.

I am going a little crazy here because I assume it is something to do with perhaps with multiple references of the same DLL somehow causing the issue (like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596796/net-unable-to-cast-object-to-interface-it-implements)). The fact that the debugger tells me everything is okay makes it hard to trouble-shoot. I'm not sure if it's relevant but I have provided example code and the file structure below:

**Shared.dll code**

```
public interface IPlugin
{
}

public class BasePlugin : IPlugin
{
}
```

**Plugin.dll code**

```
class MyPlugin : BasePlugin
{
   void Init()
   {
       // The plugin contains references to the main app dlls as it requires
       // to call various functions inside the main app such as adding menu items etc
   }
}
```

**Main.exe**

(Note: This is pseudo-code only and does not show the plugin framework used to load the plugin DLLs via `Assembly.Load()`)

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType);  // Plugin type will be 'MyPlugin'
if (obj is IPlugin)   // <== This executes as false when executed but evaluates to true in the Visual Studio debugger
{
}

var castObj = (IPlugin)obj  // <== This will cause an invalid cast exception
```

**Folder structure**

```
|--- MainApp.exe
|--- Shared.dll
|--- Addins
|------- Plugin.dll
|------- Shared.dll
```

Does anyone know the reasons how I can trouble-shoot this issue and what might be causing it?

Comment: When you have duplicate classes it is best to reference the class by it full name including namespace.   For example TcpClient can also be reference as System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.

Comment: There is no other class named the same. The only "duplication" would be that there are two Shared.dll's. If this were the issue, I don't understand why VS would not also give me the same exception.

Comment: None of your code performs any casts.  Did you omit that code or are you using the term  euphemistically for the `as` operator, even though such usage would never throw the exception you named?

Comment: The main code is effectively pseudo-code which demonstrates that the object is not considered an IPlugin. If I add the code "var castObj = (IPlugin)obj", it will fail with 'invalid cast' exception. That is, only if is executed in code. If I execute the same code in VS Immediate Window, everything is ok.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the `Modules` window to see whether `Shared.dll` is loading the location you expect? I've solved certain goofy behaviors in my own plugin architectures by preloading common interface and base class .dlls at the very start using `Assembly.LoadFrom`. In my case, all these different plugins were making their own local copies in their respective `bin` directories during build. What I was seeing before I put "preload from deterministic path" in place was a load-on-demand behavior that sometimes had funny ideas about what paths to probe and a stale copy might be loaded.

Comment: The dlls are the same and contain classes.  The error is due to the namespaces being different.  So solution is to make the namespaces the same.

Comment: Hi @IVSoftware, thanks for the tip about looking in Modules. I can see two of the same DLL loaded from two different folder locations. I think this is the key to the issue. It still doesn't make sense to me why VS would be using a different version of the DLL than the executing assembly. I would expect the normal execution and the debugger to have the same result.

Comment: @jdweng, Thanks for the suggestion but this isn't the problem as there are no duplicate classes/code. It seems there are two of the same DLLs loaded from different locations though and I think this is the cause.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that! I guess next I have to ask you whether any of your .dlls are signed with .snk or .pfx because that "could" create different assembly identities.

Comment: Hi @IVSoftware, the DLLs are not signed in any way. I assumed that .NET would automatically prevent the same DLL from being loaded twice based on hash or something. Not sure how the internals work on this point.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that (using the Properties\Signing tab) you sign your shared dll assembly with a [Strong Name Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/strong-named). If your plugin classes reference a signed copy of the dll, there should be no possibility of confusion.

[image: signing popup]

The application has no prior knowledge of what the plugins are going to be, but it *does* know that it's going to support `IPlugin`. Therefore, I would reference the `PlugInSDK` project directly in the app project.

**Testbench**

Here's what works for me and maybe  by comparing notes we can get to the bottom of it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
```

Confirm that the shared dll (known here as **PlugInSDK.dll**) has already been loaded and display the source location. In the Console output, note the that `PublicKeyToken` is *not* null for the `SDK` assembly (this is due to the snk signing).
[image: 'PlugInSDK, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d47bcb0b1dd9d79']

```
    var sdk = 
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Single(asm=>(Path.GetFileName(asm.Location) == "PlugInSDK.dll"));
    Console.WriteLine(
        $"'{sdk.FullName}'\nAlready loaded from:\n{sdk.Location}\n");
```

The `AssemblyLoad` event provides the means to examine on-demand loads as they occur:

```
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyLoad += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var name = e.LoadedAssembly.FullName;
        if (name.Split(",").First().Contains("PlugIn"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"{name}\nLoaded on-demand from:\n{e.LoadedAssembly.Location}\n");
        }
    };
```

It doesn't matter where the plugins are located, but when you go to discover them I suggest `SearchOption.AllDirectories` because they often end up in subs like **netcoreapp3.1**.

```
    var pluginPath =
        Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
            "..",
            "..",
            "..",
            "PlugIns"
        );
```

Chances are good that a copy of **PlugInSDK.dll** is going to sneak into this directory. Make sure that the discovery process doesn't accidentally pick this up. Any *other* `Type` that implements `IPlugin` gets instantiated and put in the list.

```
    List<IPlugin> plugins = new List<IPlugin>();

    foreach (
        var plugin in 
        Directory.GetFiles(pluginPath, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        // Exclude copy of the SDK that gets put here when plugins are built.
        if(Path.GetFileName(plugin) == "PlugInSDK.dll") continue;

        // Be sure to use 'LoadFrom' not 'Load'
        var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(plugin);

        // Check to make sure that any given *.dll 
        // implements IPlugin before adding to list.
        Type plugInType = 
            asm.ExportedTypes
            .Where(type =>
                type.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces
                .Any(intfc => intfc.Name == "IPlugin")
            ).SingleOrDefault();

        if ((plugInType != null) && plugInType.IsClass)
        {
            plugins.Add((IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(plugInType));
        }
    }
```

Now just display the result of the plugin discovery.

```
    Console.WriteLine("LIST OF PLUGINS");
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine, 
            plugins.Select(plugin => plugin.Name)));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Is this something you're able to repro on your side?

[image: Console output]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/plug_in_architecture.git) this sample.

Comment: Hi @IVSoftware, thanks for the framework. I've actually narrowed it down by using the Modules window in VS. It looks like a DLL was loaded twice. I think this is the cause of the problem and trying to weed it out.

Comment: Glad you're figuring it out! I guess my point was that it would be _impossible_ for a strong-named assembly to _be_ loaded twice (because that's what strong-naming is _for_) and the hope was as soon as you add the snk _boom_ whatever the issue is should be pretty obvious at that point! Anyway good luck I'm rooting for you.

Comment: Appreciate your help, @IVSoftware. Unfortunately strong naming is not an ideal option for me. It makes more sense that I ensure any lax calls to add DLL references are cleaned up.

Comment: Got it! Oh the other thing I noticed that we might be doing differently is that it looks as though you're calling `Assembly.Load` and I tend to use `Assembly.LoadFrom`. I don't know whether that's a "clue" or not :)