# Type.IsAssignableFrom() bug

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection

I'd like to load some plugin (C# assembly) at runtime and use some of the classes implementing a certain interface inside each of them.
So I wrote a base assemby (Interfaces.dll) in which I declare base interfaces:

```
namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface IPlugin01
    {
        string Name { get; }
        string Description { get; }
        void Calc1();
    }

    public interface IPlugin02
    {
        void Calc2();
    }
}
```

Then, in two different assemblies (Plugin01.dll and Plugin02.dll) I've implemented those interfaces using classes:

```
namespace Plugin01
{
    public class Class1 : Interfaces.IPlugin01,Interfaces.IPlugin02
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Plugin01.Class1"; } }
        public string Description { get { return "Plugin01.Class1 description"; } }
        public void Calc1() { Console.WriteLine("sono Plugin01.Class1 Calc1()"); }
        public void Calc2() { Console.WriteLine("sono Plugin01.Class1 Calc2()"); }
    }

    public class Class2 : Interfaces.IPlugin01
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Plugin01.Class2"; } }
        public string Description { get { return "Plugin01.Class2 description"; } }
        public void Calc1() { Console.WriteLine("sono Plugin01.Class2 Calc1()"); }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace Plugin02
{
    public class Class1 : Interfaces.IPlugin01
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Plugin02.Class1"; } }
        public string Description { get { return "Plugin02.Class1 description"; } }
        public void Calc1() { Console.WriteLine("sono Plugin02.Class1 Calc1()"); }
    }
    public class Class2 : Interfaces.IPlugin02
    {
        public void Calc2() { Console.WriteLine("sono Plugin02.Class2 Calc2()"); }
    }
}
```

Finally the test console app:

```
//#define LIST1
#define LIST2

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
#if LIST1
            List<Interfaces.IPlugin01> list1 = GetFilePlugins<Interfaces.IPlugin01>(@".\Plugins\Plugin01.dll");
#else
            List<Interfaces.IPlugin01> list1 = new List<Interfaces.IPlugin01>();
#endif

#if LIST2
            List<Interfaces.IPlugin01> list2 = GetFilePlugins<Interfaces.IPlugin01>(@".\Plugins\Plugin02.dll");
#else
            List<Interfaces.IPlugin01> list2 = new List<Interfaces.IPlugin01>();
#endif
        /// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /// If I don't load one of the assembly using LIST1 or LIST2
        /// GetDirectoryPlugins returns an empty list.
        /// The bug (is a bug or my mistake?) is inside GetFilePlugins:
        /// typeT.IsAssignableFrom(type) returns FALSE even if interface is implemented !!!
        /// Using LIST1 or LIST2 before using GetDirectoryPlugins makes
        /// typeT.IsAssignableFrom(type) return TRUE as expected !!!
        /// I'm going crazy over this....
        /// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
        List<Interfaces.IPlugin01> listtot = GetDirectoryPlugins<Interfaces.IPlugin01>(@".\Plugins\");


#if LIST1
            Console.WriteLine("--- 001 ---");
            foreach(Interfaces.IPlugin01 plugin in list1)
                plugin.Calc1();
#endif
#if LIST2
            Console.WriteLine("--- 002 ---");
            foreach (Interfaces.IPlugin01 plugin in list2)
                plugin.Calc1();
#endif
            Console.WriteLine("--- TOT ---");
            foreach (Interfaces.IPlugin01 plugin in listtot)
                plugin.Calc1();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static List<T> GetFilePlugins<T>(string filename)
        {
            List<T> ret = new List<T>();
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Type typeT = typeof(T);
                Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);
                foreach (Type type in ass.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (!type.IsClass || type.IsNotPublic) continue;
                    Debug.Print("{0} <- {1}", typeT.IsAssignableFrom(type), type);
                    if (typeT.IsAssignableFrom(type))
                    {
                        T plugin = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                        ret.Add(plugin);
                    }
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
        public static List<T> GetDirectoryPlugins<T>(string dirname)
        {
            List<T> ret = new List<T>();
            string[] dlls = Directory.GetFiles(dirname, "*.dll");
            foreach (string dll in dlls)
            {
                List<T> dll_plugins = GetFilePlugins<T>(Path.GetFullPath(dll));
                ret.AddRange(dll_plugins);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

As written in comment, if I leave both rows ***#define LIST1*** and ***#define LIST2*** commented, IsAssignableFrom() returns false even if my class implements desired interface. Why?

Comment: why are you re-inventing the wheel? Have a look at MEF - all of this is covered already.

Comment: see http://mef.codeplex.com/ for an overview - this is built into .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already answer to the same question.
Print the fully qualified names, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345413/isassignablefrom-returns-false-when-it-should-return-true/345464#345464).
You can also try calling `GetInterface`and checking for `null`.

Answer (score -1):

On a side-note regarding intuitive code and readability, which I think is related to the confusion here:

The name of the Type.IsAssignableFrom method is vague and confusing when applied to testing inheritance or detecting interface implementations.  The following wrapper for these purposes would make a lot more sense:

```
    public static bool CanBeTreatedAsType(this Type CurrentType, Type TypeToCompareWith)
    {
        // Always return false if either Type is null
        if (CurrentType == null || TypeToCompareWith == null)
            return false;

        // Return the result of the assignability test
        return TypeToCompareWith.IsAssignableFrom(CurrentType);
    }
```

Then, one can have more understandable client syntax such as:

```
    bool CanBeTreatedAs = typeof(SimpleChildClass).CanBeTreatedAsType(typeof(SimpleClass));
    CanBeTreatedAs = typeof(SimpleClass).CanBeTreatedAsType(typeof(IDisposable));
```

The advantage of this method instead of the 'is' keyword is that it can be used at run-time to test unknown, arbitrary Types, whereas the 'is' keyword (and a generic Type parameter) requires compile-time knowledge of specific Types.