# Assembly conflict when using Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am loading a DLL dynamically into an `Assembly`.  My problem is when I try to use `System.Reflection` to get a certain type from that loaded assembly, that I want to use to create an instance of that type.  The type I want happens to be an interface.

This is based on code that I have used successfully in the past, but for a new project, it fails.  The problem seems to be that the types being compared are from two different assemblies.

Here is the code:

```
IMyInterface _classInstance;

String path = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "mydynamic.dll");
if (File.Exists(path))
{
   Byte[] ba = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
   if (ba.Length > 0)
   {
      Assembly dll = Assembly.Load(ba);
      if (dll != null)
      {
         foreach (Type T in dll.GetTypes())
         {
            if (typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(T))
               _classInstance = (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(T);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Using the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345413/isassignablefrom-returns-false-when-it-should-return-true), I was able to determine that `typeof(IMyInterface).Module.FullyQualifiedName` returns the executing application (the EXE I am debugging).  That, of course, does not match what I see for `T.Module.FullyQualifiedName`, which is the DLL.

I would like to resolve this without injecting some go-between assembly that does nothing but provide the type, if that is possible.

Comment: Maybe I misread your question, but you cannot create instances of interfaces - only instances of classes implementing those interfaces.

Comment: @xxbbcc In this case, it would work because the type that passes the test will be one that implements the interface, making the cast appropriate.

Comment: Ah, ok, I saw that in your code now. I commented based on the text above the code example. :)

Comment: Do you get a run-time exception or is `_classInstance` just null after the code executes?

Comment: And you are sure that the hosting application is referencing the same version of the assembly that contains `IMyInterface` as `mydynamic.dll`

Comment: Where do you declare `IMyInterface`? The code you show will work if and only if you are actually dealing with the same type. The type you use in your loop _must_ be the same type that the DLL is using. See also [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx), as it may be applicable to your scenario.

Comment: @PhilipPittle No exceptions.  The match is never found, and the object remains `null`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The actual declaration is in both places.  It's declared in a code page that is linked in each project.  So both the EXE that is running, and the individual DLLs both know of `IMyInterface`.  It's the single bit of glue that all rely on to do work.  This is necessary because the EXE needs to be able to call a standard set of methods, while leaving the implementation to the DLL that has been loaded.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Futher, I think I stated that I realize it's finding the type in two places, and thus failing the match.  The very question is what I can/should do about that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Satisfaction for the curious...

The answer came down to making a small concession in the project design.  Instead of linking the interface class (code page) into each project, and allowing each project to be its own stand-alone entity, I had to only reference that class in the main EXE project.  And instead of incorporating their own links to `IMyInterface` , the individual DLLs make a an assembly reference to that EXE project.

This resolved the incompatibility issue between the EXE's type and the loaded DLL's type.

I say "small concession" because the design was always to have a DLL in the EXE's working directory that would be loaded at runtime, so the project reference changes nothing philosophically.