# Why do I get errors when trying to resolve a derived type during deserialization? (Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: c#, json, json.net, revit-api

I get errors whenever I try to deserialize classes from json whenever the serialized data contains a derrived type. My end goal is to be able to store a variety of derived types so this is a problem. The error does not occur when I store only non-derived types in object I serialized. For added context the code is part of an add-in being run using Revit's AddinManager extension.

(Upon suggestion, I reworked the code to try and isolate the problem and give a more conveyable description. I have changed the code to use two simple classes instead.)

After the changes I now get the Error:

> Type specified in JSON 'AddinNamespace.ToyNodePlus, AddinAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible with 'AddinNamespace.ToyNode, AddinAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Path 'TestNode.$type', line 1, position 61.

AddinSettings

```
namespace AddinNamespace
{
    public class AddinSettings
    {   
        public const string Filename = "AddinSettings.json";

        public ToyNode TestNode;
    }
}
```

ToyNode and ToyNodePlus definitions

```
namespace AddinNamespace
{
    public class ToyNode
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    public class ToyNodePlus : ToyNode
    {
        public int AdditionalValue;
    }
}
```

Serialization Code

```
private JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = null;

private void OnAddinStart(){
    serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() 
    { 
    TypeNameHandling=TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling = TypeNameAssemblyFormatHandling.Simple
    };
    if(File.Exists(AddinSettings.Filename)){
        string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(AddinSettings.Filename);
        AddinSettings settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddinSettings> (fileContents, serializerSettings);

        //do work with settings here
    }
}

//code for saving to Json (code appears to be working as expected)
private void OnAddinFinish(){
    AddinSettings settings = new AddinSettings();
    settings.TestNode = new ToyNodePlus() {AdditionalValue = 7, Name= "This is a test" };
    string fileContents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings, serializerSettings);
    File.WriteAllText(AddinSettings.Filename, fileContents);
}
```

Created Json File Contents

```
{"TestNode":{"$type":"AddinNamespace.ToyNodePlus, AddinAssembly","AdditionalValue":7,"Name":"This is a test"}}
```

Comment: What is settings in the last code snippet ?

Comment: How are you defining the list of objects? could you post the structure/class definition of whichever type `settings` is?

Comment: Indeed, if you could include a [mcve] that would make it easier to help you.

Comment: I've edited the question to be hopefully be more easily reproducible.

Comment: It's still not a [mcve]. I can't just copy, paste, compile, run and see the problem. I *could* build everything up from the snippets you've got here, but it's inefficient for each interested person to do that when you could do that *once* and end up with a clearer question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm actually a bit new to actively using this site. If you think it would help, I can change my question to include code that is runnable by copy pasting from one block. However, based on my own tests simply pasting this code into a console application would not reproduce the problem. The code is being run by the Addin Manager inside Autodesk Revit and debugger lead me to believe it is caused by a caching error. If you have suggestions on how to improve the question, I would appreciate it if you submitted an edit request.

Comment: I ended up reworking the question again based on your suggestions. Hope it reads better.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. I actually had to look through the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs) on github to find the answer, but I eventually was able to find out which line the error occurs on.

This specific error is thrown by a check in JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolveTypeName(..) when the following check is triggered

```
!objectType.IsAssignableFrom(specifiedType)
```

Looking into the error eventually turned up this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/345413/isassignablefrom-returns-false-when-it-should-return-true).
The specific problem in my case was caused because my code was being called as a class library and the calling application was caching old .dll files in a temp folder after the first call. Because the dlls were technically different `Type.IsAssignable(Type)` returned false.

I ended up having to write a custom SerializationBinder and adding it to the JsonSerializerSettings parameter in order to make sure that consistent assemblies were used. (Implementation below). I am not sure if this was the best way to handle it, so if anyone has any alternative solutions or improvements...

```
class CustomSerializationBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    private Dictionary<string, Assembly> assemblyLookup = new Dictionary<string, Assembly>();
    private Dictionary<string, Type> typeCache = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    public CustomSerializationBinder(List<Assembly> problemAssemblies = null)
    {
        if (problemAssemblies == null) problemAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
        foreach(Assembly assembly in problemAssemblies)
        {
            if(!assemblyLookup.ContainsKey(assembly.GetName().Name))
                this.assemblyLookup.Add(assembly.GetName().Name,assembly);
        }
        foreach(Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            if(!assemblyLookup.ContainsKey(assembly.GetName().Name))
                assemblyLookup.Add(assembly.GetName().Name, assembly);
        }
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = serializedType.Assembly.FullName;
        typeName = serializedType.FullName;
    }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type resolvedType;
        Assembly resolvedAssembly;
        typeCache.TryGetValue(typeName, out resolvedType);
        if (resolvedType != null) return resolvedType;

        assemblyLookup.TryGetValue(assemblyName, out resolvedAssembly);
        if (resolvedAssembly == null) return null;
        resolvedType = resolvedAssembly.GetType(typeName);
        if (resolvedType != null)
            typeCache.Add(typeName, resolvedType);
        return resolvedType;
    }
}
```