# .Net core and plugins

Tags: .net, plugins, .net-core

Following this lecture (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support), I managed to create an app based on plugins. So far so good.
But, I want to do more with my plugins. Hence, for one of them, I created an additional library. Of course, when developing my plugin, I got a library dependance to this lib I created.
The problem is more on execution. When running my app, more especially when the plugin executes its task, I have an exception raised saying:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibObjectsLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

MyLibObjectsLib is of course the additional library used by the called plugin.
Is there something I missed?

Comment: The tutorial you point is working fine in .Net Core, Can you provide the sample project?

Comment: Hi Hassan,Thanks for your comment. You're right, I had to look closer to the tutorial example. I corrected that by doing in my plugin `code`Assembly acAssembly = typeof(MyLibClass).Assembly;
            var libType = acAssembly.GetType("System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection");
            ObjectType instance = (ObjectType)Activator.CreateInstance(libType);`code`and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

The tutorial use a custom ALC (AssemblyLoadContext) to load only one  plugin assembly which doesn't depend on others.

In your case, the custom ALC load the plugin and resolve all dependencies.

In the [custom ALC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support#load-plugins), you note that it  uses [AssemblyDependencyResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblydependencyresolver?view=netcore-3.1) ( a new class in .Net Core 3.0+)

The AssemblyDependencyResolver class enables the application developers to more easily develop a plugin architecture in conjunction with custom System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext instances to isolate plugins and also enable plugins to load dependencies.

**Important Remark:**

Plugins should include `ExcludeAssets=runtime` for project references to shared assemblies, [ref](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/15811).

For example, If the project `Common` that include the interface `IContract' and is referenced by the both host application and the plugin project, add reference as given below:

```xml
<!-- in the plugin project -->

<ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\IContract\Common.csproj">
            <Private>false</Private>
            <ExcludeAssets>runtime</ExcludeAssets>
        </ProjectReference>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MyLibObjectsLib\MyLibObjectsLib.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

This code is used for loading the plugin:

```cs
string pluginPath = @"path/to/MyContract.Plugin.dll";           
var assembly = new PluginLoadContext(pluginPath).LoadFromAssemblyPath(pluginPath);

var type = assembly.GetTypes()
       .FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsAbstract);     

if (type != null) {
     var instance = (IContract)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
     var ret = instance.Execute();     
}
```

I simulated your plugin as standard2.0 library and the plugin reference OLEDB nuget package and the plugin is loaded without errors.